# Flutter: Display the total score / level to the user

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have `score`, `topicTotal` and `level` set in the state and I am printing each of them. The `topicTotal` is the final score where all scores are added onto each other and the `level` is based on their `topicTotal`.

`score` is coming from Firebase for each question. I want to calculate a total score based on the sum of `score` and I want to display a level to the user depending on the total score.

Even though, I am able to print `score`, `topicTotal` and `level`, I cannot display these values  to the user.

How can I display these values to the user and if I can't display them from the state, how can I retrieve and display them using a different approach?

```
class AssessmentState with ChangeNotifier {
  double _progress = 0;
  Options _selected;
  dynamic _score;
  dynamic _topicTotal;

  final PageController controller = PageController();
  var idx = 0;

  get progress => _progress;
  get selected => _selected;
  get score => _score;
  get topicTotal => _topicTotal;

  set progress(double newValue) {
    _progress = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set selected(Options newValue) {
    _selected = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set score(dynamic newValue) {
    var score = idx += newValue.score;
    _score = newValue;
    print(score);
    _score = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set topicTotal(dynamic newValue) {
    var topicTotal = idx;
    print(topicTotal);
    if (topicTotal <= 300) {
      print('Level 1');
    } else if (topicTotal <= 900) {
      print('Level 2');
    } else if (topicTotal <= 1400) {
      print('Level 3');
    } else
      print('Level 4');
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

```
  final Assessment assessment;
  final Questions questions;
  final Options options;
  final Options optionSelected;
  WellDonePage({this.assessment, this.questions, this.options, this.optionSelected});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var state = Provider.of<AssessmentState>(context);

    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Well Done! You completed the ${assessment.title} Assessment. Your level for the ${assessment.title} Assessment is ${state.topicTotal}',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use builder method
something like this

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
 stream: Firestore.instance.collection('DriverList').snapshots(),
 builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
   if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
   return new ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
         return new ListTile(
            title: new Text(document['name']),
            subtitle: new Text(document['phone']),
         );
      }).toList(),
   );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss type in `set topicTotal`

```
set topicTotal(dynamic newValue) {
  var topicTotal = idx; // this line should change to "_topicTotal = idx;"
  print(topicTotal);
```

which can actually update the value when you try to get.

```
get topicTotal => _topicTotal;
```